# Vaadin maven import abstract ui issue

Tags: java, maven, jar, vaadin, war

I should create a common vaadin project shared among two others.
The parent project has got a the UI class as an abstract class:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public abstract class AbstractUI extends UI {

  public abstract Map<String, Class<? extends View>> getViewsMap();

  @Override
  protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

This parent project than is packaged as jar and imported as maven dependency from the child.

The child is a vaadin maven war project, extending the abstract ui class from the parent and implementing his abstract method.

```
public class MyUI extends AbstractUI {

  @Override
  public Map<String, Class<? extends View>> getViewsMap() {
    [...]
  }

}
```

Eclipse doesn't complain at all about this, but when I run my vaadin application inside Tomcat I get this exception:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Vaadin Application Servlet] in context with path [/admin-dashboard] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/to/AbstractUI] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.to.AbstractUI
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at com.vaadin.server.ServletPortletHelper.verifyUIClass(ServletPortletHelper.java:70)
at com.vaadin.server.ServletPortletHelper.initDefaultUIProvider(ServletPortletHelper.java:156)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.createAndRegisterSession(VaadinService.java:770)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.doFindOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:724)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:665)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:524)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The web.xml inside the child project is the following one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.to.MyUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: the class can not be found.  have you checked the war, that the class is there?

Comment: Following @cfrick 's suggestion, do you package the parent dependency when building the war, can you show us the pom?

Comment: the parent is included as jar library inside the \WEB-INF\lib and I just doublechecked I've got it inside my deployed war

Comment: Is it a valid jar file? Can you doublecheck that the AbstractUI class is present in the expected package. Also please use @username when replying so we get notified of new comments.